# How to avoid "Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line"?

Tags: raster, gdal, r, netcdf, hdf

I am trying to re-project from Equi-rectangular to the NASA global EASE grid (Equal Area Scalable Earth) grid 1383 586 with a ~25 km cylindrical projection (ESPG=3410). The file is provided as HDF5.

But I am facing an error:

> gdal_translate -of "ENVI" HDF5:"C:\Users\GW1AM2_20120930_01D_EQMD_L3SG
>   SMCHA1110100.h5"://Time_Information C:\Users\amsr2_time.img
>
> gdalwarp  -of "ENVI" -overwrite -ts 1383 586 -t_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0
>   =0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs" -ot Float32 C:\Users\amsr2_time.img C:\Users\amsr2_time_ease.img

```
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line
and georeferenced coordinates for C:\Users\amsr2_time.img.
There is no affine transformation and no GCPs.
```

The file can be downloaded as both `HDF5` and NETCDF` formats here:

http://gcom-w1.jaxa.jp/OrderFiles/31DaKuDQzFDeAgM0/31DaKuDQzFDeAgM0_0.zip